# Is there a way to bake an array animation?

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, file-format

I have an object with an array modifier. I animate this array, using empty as “object offset” (like in this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COCFd_BKqLw ).

**Is there a way to bake an array animation** (in order to export it to another program later)? I need to save this animation, without the array modifer, which is supported only by Blender.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have no Idea how could it be done exactly (probably with some python code) but It would be great to know it, so I'm waiting for an answer with you.

Comment: @Mzidare Thank you, yes, it would be great and quite usefull!

Comment: If i understood your question right watch this[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w21Rt.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w21Rt.gif)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to simply "bake" an array animation, unfortunately, to export it to other programs, since it usually creates and deforms a lot of new "virtual" geometry (in a procedural way), and in many possible ways. It doesn't just transform or deform meshes. Not an easy task.

Comment: Baking an array animation is like applying the modifier when not animated.  But why apply a modifier? Normally, you don't do it, so why in an animation?

Answer (score 6):

If the software you want to export it to supports alembic (i know for example that fusion does), you can use this fileformat. It was just added to Blender so it only works in the newest Versions. Exporting it in Blender and importing it again works fine and it bakes the animation to mesh cache (In Blender it then uses the mesh cache modifier). This is also how you can export fluid simulations for example.

Just choose File - Export: alembic (.abc) and configure the options (especially the end frame)
[image]

Comment: That's an amazing trick would never have thought of that one!